# Как сделать Матово-прозрачную форму в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Хотел бы я узнать как сделать матово-прозрачную форму по типу UWP прозрачности

[image: Пример прозрачности шапки калькулятора]

Чтобы было похоже на шапку калькулятора(матово прозрачная)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63216168/12888024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такие пакеты, называются FluentWPF.

https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF - популярный

https://github.com/ju2pom/FluentWPF - непопулярный, не обновляется